# Perspective distort not working in Rails MiniMagick project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, minimagick

I'm trying to get this code to work in my rails project but i'm getting the following error:

```
image_process.html.erb:62: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
c.distort :Perspective "0,0 -30,20  0,200 -30,179  40...
```

here is my code:

```
left_piece = MiniMagick::Image.open("public/#{@asset.file_name.url}")
left_piece.crop("50x500+0+0")
left_piece.combine_options do |c|
c.alpha "set"
c.virtual_pixel "transparent"
c.distort :Perspective "0,0 -30,20  0,200 -30,179  40,200 0,200  40,0 0,0"
end
```

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to create a 3d box http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.. please help!!

Edit:

When I try

```
c.distort :Perspective, "0,0 -30,20  0,200 -30,179  40,200 0,200  40,0 0,0"
```

I get the following error:

```
mogrify.exe: unable to open image `-30,20': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `-30,20' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
mogrify.exe: unable to open image `0,200': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `0,200' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
mogrify.exe: unable to open image `-30,179': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `-30,179' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
mogrify.exe: unable to open image `40,200': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `40,200' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
mogrify.exe: unable to open image `0,200': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `0,200' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
mogrify.exe: unable to open image `40,0': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `40,0' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
mogrify.exe: unable to open image `0,0': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `0,0' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
mogrify.exe: invalid argument for option Affine : 'require at least 1 CPs' @ error/distort.c/GenerateCoefficients/530.
```

Comment: Try tossing a comma in after `:Perspective`. As in: `c.distort :Perspective, "0,0 -30,20  0,200 -30,179  40,200 0,200  40,0 0,0"`

Comment: See edited post for the error I get when I put in the comma

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this the fix was

```
c.distort :Perspective "0,0,-30,20,0,200,-30,179,40,200,0,200,40,0,0,0"
```